# Why is it showing that Problem uploading to board in my Arduino project?

Tags: arduino

I've faced my Arduino project. When I'm going to upload my code on the board then It's showing the error of the attached image bellow. How can I upload my code without this error? Or any solution for that?

[image]

Comment: do you have an Arduino attached on that COM port?

Comment: Yes I've. But still showing the error. :(

Comment: and the right board and port is selected in Tools menu?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, you are trying to upload sketch to arduino with older, or even missing bootloader. The solution is:

- Programmers' method: plug out, and then in again
- Load a new bootloader to your board.
- Check the solutions [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=609235.0)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Bluetooth module connected?

If the answer is "yes", that may be the problem. Just disconnect it, upload your code, and then connect it again.

If you disconnect it and still have the same problem, your Arduino may be damaged.